# If $\tau \equiv \min\{n:X_1+ X_2 +\cdots+ X_n > k\}$, how to show $\mathbb{E}(\tau) = 1 + {k \over \mu}$ for exponential random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be i.i.d where $X_i \sim \mathrm{Exponential}(\frac{1}{\mu})$, and suppose $k$ is a positive
constant. Define $\tau \equiv \min\{n:X_1+ X_2 +\cdots+ X_n > k\}.$
I would like to show that $\mathbb{E}(\tau) = 1 + {k \over \mu}.$ Is there a way to use Wald's theorem for this?

Comment: Yes. $E(S_\tau)=k+\mu$ by memorylessness property and $E(S_\tau)=\mu E(\tau)$ by Wald's identity.

Comment: Could you elaborate how you obtained $E(S_{\tau}) = k+ \mu$? thanks

Comment: $X_{\tau}\sim k-S_{\tau-1}+\exp(\mu^{-1})$ by memorylessness.

Comment: Sorry, I am not really sure how you got this, is there a standard way of deriving this?

Comment: How is $S_{\tau}$ related to $k$? What about $S_{\tau-1}$? Now note that $X_{\tau}=S_\tau-S_{\tau-1}$ and is exponential.

Comment: I can't see why $E(S_{\tau})=k+\mu$.. Can you show that step by step?